# Can't print double braces ({{) into browser side

Tags: html, angularjs, django, python-2.7

I'm trying to get

```
<a class='js-acnhor-scroll' target="_self" 
   data-ng-href="#{{rc.prepareUrlParam(metric_group.title)}}" 
   data-ng-bind="metric_group.title">
</a>
```

as is in the browser side, but the python think it's a variable and throw the error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '(metric_group.title)' from 'rc.prepareUrlParam(metric_group.title)'
```

How can I send it include the double braces (`{{`) to the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`{% verbatim %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#verbatim) template block to prevent that Django parses that part of the template:

```
{% verbatim %}data-ng-href="#{{rc.prepareUrlParam(metric_group.title)}}" {% endverbatim %}
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`{% templatetag %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#templatetag) template tag to output the literal `{{` and `}}`:

```
data-ng-href="#{% templatetag openvariable %}rc.prepareUrlParam(metric_group.title){% templatetag closevariable %}"
```

Both methods allow you to output a literal `{{` or `}}` from a Django template, which can then be parsed and handled by AngularJS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to double the braces `{{` or `}}` to output a single brace `{` or `}`. Can you try doing this:

```
#{{{{rc.prepareUrlParam(metric_group.title)}}}}"
```

Check this out:

```
>>> x = " {{ Hello }} {0} "
>>> print x.format(42)
' { Hello } 42 '
```

Comment: It's work with your example, but now I'm getting: "Could not parse the remainder: '{{rc.prepareUrlParam(metric_group.title)'..."

Comment: Like what? Can you post it fully?

Comment: I changed to data-ng-href="#{{{{rc.prepareUrlParam(metric_group.title)}}}}" and the error is: TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '{{rc.prepareUrlParam(metric_group.title)' from '{{rc.prepareUrlParam(metric_group.title)'